# PHP Datatable currency sorting

Tags: php, jquery, sorting, datatable, currency

I got problem with my data table sorting in the currency tab. when i try to sort the currency/price column..

Ex

```
A - $ 10,0000
B - $ 4,000
C - $ 8,000
```

In Chrome:

it works fine it displays the correct answer. which is `BCA` Ascending Order.

In Mozilla and IE:

it doesn't display the correct answer instead it will display this answer `ACB` Ascending order. I believe it reads the second lowest number since moz and iE reads the $ sign as a part of the string.

Any solution for this?

you may try this sample [link](http://imperialsolutions.jp/stocks/) that I found 
open it in Chrome and Mozilla

Comment: What code are you using for the sort? Otherwise, it's not possible to tell what might be wrong.

Comment: its a built in code sorting in http://datatables.net/

Comment: What code are *you* using for this? Could you provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Im using included JS Datatable from my php project. In JS Datatable it has a built in sorting module.

Comment: That doesn't really help. There are two problems with your question: Firstly, you're linking to a separate website and assuming they have the identical problem (which isn't necessarily the case, and isn't very future-proof), and secondly you're linking to the resource you're using which *doesn't* have this problem. Please provide the code *you* are using.

Comment: I'm sorry.. but that site / link that I provide you is the project that i created. it has a problem with the sorting in FOB prices. it can't be sort well in Mozilla or IE. but working in chrome. 

It uses Datatable.js.. If you really wanted the code. 

You can download it here at datatables.net which is the JS file.
and the code would be simple as this:

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
} );`

Comment: You probably need to remove the $ and convert the 1,000 to the number 1000 without a comma, and by number I mean a real number that is for example returned by `parseInt`. Otherwise a string compare will be used, and there 800>2000. You probably need to write a plugin similar to the numeric sorting plugin here: http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/type-detection

Comment: @Adder Hi! the data's that I use in this table are real numbers, the $ is concat to make as USD Currency. If I remove the $ sign it display correctly in IE and FireFox. 

I already tried the link that you posted. It gives me an error regarding with the function.. its like fnExeger.. something. I forgot the name of the function. But I'll try this again.

Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: @Adder Hi! this is the error that I get in adding those plugins - Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_fnEscapeRegex'

Answer (score 0):

I just solve my problem.

Instead of creating a extended .js file for the currency plugin which causes error.. I write code together with the creating the datatable object. something like this:

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
            model_select();
            $('.data_table').dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bRetrieve":true,
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                  { "sType": "currency", "aTargets": [ 10 ] }
                ]
            }); 
            // Change this list to the valid characters you want
            var validChars = "$£€c0123456789-,";

            // Init the regex just once for speed - it is "closure locked"
            var str = jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oApi._fnEscapeRegex("$£€c0123456789-,");
            var re = new RegExp('[^'+str+']');


            jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.aTypes.unshift(
               function ( data )
                {
                    if ( typeof data !== 'string' || re.test(data) ) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    return 'currency';
                }
            );              
        });
```